# Scroll in parallax work incorrect?

Tags: scroll, parallax

When I use scroll in parallax for first div, the next div is pushed down. It betray backgound in blue. How can I fix it?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.parent .mid .main-slide').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, -' + wScroll / 10 + '%)'
  });



});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}
.parent .header {
  width: 100%;
}
/*menu-first*/

.parent .header .menu-first {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #dc6453;
  border-top: solid 5px #bf6053;
}
.parent .header .menu-first .contact {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.parent .header .menu-first .contact ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
.parent .header .menu-first .search-box {
  float: right;
  width: 41%;
  padding: 1%;
}
.parent .header .menu-first .search-box .hotline,
.txt-search,
.cart-stt {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
/*/////////////////////////menu-second///////////////////////*/

.parent .header .menu-second {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.parent .header .menu-second .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.parent .header .menu-second .menu-prod {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.parent .header .menu-second .menu-prod ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
/*///////////////////MID/////////////*/

.parent .mid {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.parent .mid .main-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
.parent .mid .main-slide .title-slide {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.parent .mid .main-prod {
  width: 100%;
}
.parent .mid .main-prod .prod-left,
.prod-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
.parent .mid .main-prod .prod-left .content-prod-left {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menu-first">
        <div class="contact">
          <ul>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Map</li>
            <li>Help</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="search-box">
          <div class="hotline">08-999-9999</div>
          <div class="txt-search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
          </div>
          <div class="cart-stt">Cart</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="menu-second">
        <div class="logo">LOGO CONG TY</div>
        <div class="menu-prod">
          <ul>
            <li>Product 1</li>
            <li>Product 2</li>
            <li>Product 2</li>
            <li>Product 2</li>
            <li>Product 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mid">
      <div class="main-slide" style="background-image: url(http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/woocommerce_54050/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bg_pic.jpg);">
        <div class="title-slide">
          A comprehensive quality control for customer satisfaction!
          <br />Reliable transportation is guaranteed!

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-prod" style="background-image: url(http://livedemo00.template-help.com/woocommerce_54050/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bg_pic2.jpg);">
        <div class="prod-left">
          <div class="content-prod-left">
            Content here!
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Tried to improve some grammar, removed the noise and moved the code from the jsfiddle to the stack snippet

Comment: @Bowdzone Can you help me. That my all code. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsjmHIGBo1WOWVEWl8tT3lzSXc/view
When i scroll, it leak blue backgound, distance between "main-slide" and "main-prod".
You can dowload it and save it as .html. Please help me!